# Linq C# method syntax, join 3 tables

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an ASP.NET C# WebApi with linq.

I have this three tables: clients, contacts and departments. In "contacts" table I just save the "id (departamento)" from the department that the contact belong, so in my view i need to show the "description (nombre)". What I have now is the following:

Tables:

[image]

Controller:

```
        public clientes GetById(int id)
    {
        projectEntities context = null;
        clientes result = null;

        try
        {
            context = GetContext();
            result = context.clientes
                .Include(e => e.clientes_contactos)
                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.cve_cliente == id);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
        finally
        {
            context?.Dispose();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

With this I get the information of the client and the contacts but deparment is showing just the id. 
What I'm trying to accomplish is this sql query:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.nombre from clientes as a inner join clientes_contactos as b on a.cve_cliente = b.cve_cliente inner join cat_departamentos as c on b.departamento = c.cve_departamentos where a.cve_cliente = 2006
```

Let me know if I'm missing some information, thanks a lot!

**SOLVED**

As @VadimBondaruk said, just needed to add this line:

```
.Include(e => e.clientes_contactos.Select(cc => cc.cat_departament))
```

Thanks!

Comment: try this:
result = context.clientes
                .Include(e => e.clientes_contactos)
                .ThenInclude(cc => cc.cat_departament).FirstOrDefault(e => e.cve_cliente == id);

Comment: Thanks, I already try that but that's not valid since cat_department has no relationship with clients. It only has it with contacts. @VadimBondaruk

Comment: which version of Entity Framework do you use?

Comment: It's 6.2.0 @VadimBondaruk

Comment: .Include(e => e.clientes_contactos.Select(cc => cc.cat_departament))

Comment: Omg, it totally works! Thank you! @VadimBondaruk

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to LINQ as

```
var query = (from a in context.clientes 
        join b in context.clientes_contactos on a.cve_cliente equals b.cve_cliente
        join c in context.cat_departamentos on b.departamento  equals c.cve_departamentos
                 where a.cve_cliente == 2006
                 select new {
                     a = a,
                     b = b,
                     c = c
                 })
```